# Making start activity that only runs once

Tags: java, android, xml, passwords, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to make an activity that lauches first, and once done, wont load anymore in app.
It's actually activity to input master password, which will be stored in classic login screen.
I have seen similar question on stackoverflow, but i didn't manage to solve to problem, kinda newbie here.
If you could post code sample aswell that would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to check like this

```
     SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("mySHaredpref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        boolean isFirst = prefs.getBoolean("isfirstTime", true);
        if(isFirst) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivityName.class);
            editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_FIRST_TIME, false);
            editor.commit();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else{
           // condition
        }
```

Comment: @Nilesh--What is `shardPrefName`? And `KEY_IS_FIRST_TIME`? And `SetupActivity`?

Comment: i have edited may answer please check it

Comment: So i make new activity, and put that code in it? Could you please explain just a little, it would be very helpfull.

Comment: put your code in activity where your launching your on time master password activity

Comment: will do. i will update you soon if i have some problem that can't solve/solved it. thanks m8!

Comment: Hey man, 1 more question: How to add in else{ } to start another activity, if its not first run?